# Elementor button to section doesn't work after scrolling down

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

I have these fixed buttons that redirect you to a specific section of the page. They work perfectly fine when you click on them starting from the top of the page, but once you scroll down a little, it does not work anymore. It will scroll down to another space in another section.

[Top of the website]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/e69NY.jpg)

[Result after clicking on "Services" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpSnw.jpg). This is the result I want everytime.

[scrolling down a little]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoPWI.jpg)

[Result after clicking on "Services" button when scrolled down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZUAq.jpg)

I also tried menu anchors, but the result is the same once I scroll down a little.